# On the evaluation of $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n \log n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

I have tried to evaluate the series $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n \log n}$. I get that it converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ but there must be a flaw in my reason since then result I get does not match that of Wolfram's Alpha.

Let me show you my work.

One good way to begin with is to recall the known Fourier series

\begin{equation} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx}{n^s} =\frac{1}{2} \bigg({\rm Li}_s  \left ( e^{-ix} \right ) + {\rm Li}_s \left ( e^{ix} \right ) \bigg) \end{equation}

where ${\rm Li}_s$ is the polylogarithm of order $s$. Hence

\begin{equation} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx}{n^s} = - \cos x + \frac{1}{2} \bigg({\rm Li}_s  \left ( e^{-ix} \right ) + {\rm Li}_s \left ( e^{ix} \right ) \bigg) \end{equation}

We differentiate with respect to $s$ , hence

\begin{equation} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx}{n^s \log n} =  \frac{e^{ix}}{2} {\rm Li}_{s-1} \left ( e^{-ix} \right ) + \frac{e^{-ix}}{2} {\rm Li}_{s-1} \left ( e^{ix} \right ) \end{equation}

For $x=\pi$ and $s=1$ we have that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n \log n} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: ehm..
$\partial_sn^{-s}=-\log(n)n^{-s}$, you would rather have to integrate the both sides w.r.t to $s$, which seems troublesome

Comment: @tired Besides the sign , which is a silly mistake by my part ... why integrate?

Comment: differentiation gets you a $\log$ into the numerator, but you want a $\log$ into the denominator which can be achived by the integration i mentioned

Comment: Whoops! What silly mistakes I made!!

Comment: that happens from time to time :)

Comment: By the way I had asked the same problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178873/on-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac-1nn-log-n?rq=1 but this time tackled it different.. Sort to say.. Good for me!! I failed miserably due to my silly mistakes

Comment: Use https://approach0.xyz/search/ to see if the question was posted earlier. It is a search engine for MSE. I also forget questions I asked as well.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai  I knew I had asked but prefered to post my new efforts in a new post.. :) \

Comment: I wouldn't encourage that. Because the question will be closed eventually.

Comment: So be it.. Besides it is wrong anyway!